# How can I have a Python script run in the background. I'm using terminal and SSH

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm connected to a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian lite, using PuTTY with SSH. To execute a Python script, I'm navigating to the script's directory and using `python3 scriptname.py`, (this script is always running, unless being modified) after doing this, all I can see is the script's console log, and I don't think I'm able to do anything else with the Pi, unless if I stop the scripts execution.

Is there anyway that I can send that process to the background, and continue to use the interface to do other things

Comment: Just append `&` after `python3 scriptname.py`

Comment: What's to prevent you starting a second `ssh` session in a different terminal?

Comment: take a look https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the different solutions. I don't know why it didn't occur to me that opening a new terminal session would truly act as a new session, I would've guessed it would essentially clone the output, but thanks Mark. Thanks coderasha, I might use Linux Screen sometime. Also, thanks Dinko, I wasn't aware I could append executions using `&`!